# Dynamic values in javascript - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js i am sending the values to html through

```
render('/abc', mydata)
```

"mydata" contains json_encoded format.

And i am reading this as :

```
{{=mydata}}
```

Now, in the same html page i have javascript like :

```
 <script>
 xyz(); 
  function xyz() { 
      // i need to read the "mydata" here.
  }
 </script>
```

I tried this which didn't work `xyz({{=mydata}})` , How can i use that dynamic data in node.js ??

Comment: Which view engine is this using? And, what is the result of `xyz({{=mydata}})` as seen by the browser?

Comment: m using express framework. And when i add that xyz({{=mydata}}) i can see an object being printed when i inspect element. But my JS fails to work

Comment: What is the value for `app.set('view engine', ???)`? Express isn't a view engine itself and the answer will likely vary based on which you're using with Express.

Comment: can u please tell me, where this would be set ??

Comment: I am unsure on where that is set !!. Can u please tell me where i can find that ?

Comment: That depends on your project structure. But, is often in the same `.js` file that uses `.listen(port)` to begin accepting requests. It's often named `app.js` or `server.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- `mydata` may not actually be a local in the view.

  Express can't pass along the name of the variable used as the argument. Only the properties of the `Object` it references.

  So, you may need to create a new `Object` around `mydata` to name a property for it:

  ```
  render('/abc', { mydata: mydata });
  ```
- The output may be HTML-encoded by `{{= }}`, which will likely cause SyntaxErrors in JavaScript.

  So, the response may contain something like:

  ```
  xyz({&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;})
  ```

  Rather than:

  ```
  xyz({"foo":"bar"})
  ```

  How to go about skipping HTML-encoding will depend on which view engine you're using with Express. But, it may be as simple as replacing the `=` with a `-`:

  ```
  xyz({{-mydata}})
  ```
- `mydata` may still be an `Object` rather than the `String` of `json_encoded` data it seems you were expecting.

  If that's the case, it may be using the [standard `.toString()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2), which will produce:

  ```
  xyz([object Object])
  ```

  And, you may still need to `stringify()` `mydata`.

  ```
  xyz({{-JSON.stringify(mydata)}})
  ```

Comment: When i inspect element, i can see it as [Object object] on this xyz({{=mydata}}

Comment: Hey, its working but with a slight change xyz({{=JSON.stringify(mydata)}}). Thank you very much